# Wireshark not capturing port 2000

Tags: tcp, wireshark

If I enter "port 2000" in the capture filter I am not getting packets from my application that is communicating via TCP on port 2000... Any idea why?

Comment: My application is sending to port 2001 from port 2000 on the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is on the same host, your application may be using the loopback interface.

On Linux you can listen to the loopback interface by selecting the "lo" device.

On Windows it's a bit [trickier](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark will not capture local traffic on windows machine without some jiggering. see Devon_C_Millers answer